# single page various calculation scripts

Tags: javascript, calculator

I want to incorporate on some of my pages various very simple calculators - user inputs one or two variables (height, weight .. whatever) clicks submit button and get's a result instantly on the same page. There are many formulas that I want to use.
My question as a non programmer is - what is the best way to approach this. Shouls I be looking for some javascript scripts/forms? Can you point me to right direction here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: JavaScript may do Math, you can use it.

Comment: "My question as a non programmer is" --- hire a developer or learn how to program from the very basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with people who suggests you to learn basics of programming. 
On the other hand this is the direct answer to your question.
(using jQuery)

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="var1" />
    +
    <input type="text" id="var2" />
    <input type="submit" value="=" />
</form>
<span id="result"></span>​
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('form').submit(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#result').text(parseInt($('#var1').val())+parseInt($('#var2').val()));           
    }
);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XvQjb/

Comment: Thank you, I am going to learn basic math functions in javacstript:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a right direction for you: http://www.codecademy.com/

That site provide easy (probably the easiest) way to learn basics of JavaScript.